# segmentation fault with char array in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

please tell me why this code give me segmentation fault?
I want to split the command into tokens but I don't know why it give me segmentation fault!!

```
char command[500]="asdadas asdasdas asdadas";   
int i,j,k;
char tokens[4][200];

for(i=0,j=0,k=0;  i<strlen(command);  i++)
{
    if(command[i]==' ') 
    {
        tokens[j][k]='\0';
        k=0;
        j++;
        continue;
    }

    tokens[j][k]=command[i];
    k++;
}
tokens[j][k]='\0';
```

Comment: Splitting a string into tokens is `strtok`'s whole purpose for existence.

Comment: `command` is uninitialised, unless that code has been omitted?

Comment: It runs without segfaulting for me.

Comment: Here too runs without segfault... In using ubuntu.

Comment: @wallyk it will probably, as soon as more than 4 spaces are in the `command` (I really do not understand what this piece of code is supposed to do....)

Comment: Please post a small compilable program that exhibits the problem. I can't see how the posted code can cause a segmentation fault with that input (even though there is no array bounds protection on `tokens`).

Comment: @BartFriederichs: It is parsing a command into words (called tokens).  It was designed for up to 4 words, though each can be quite long.  Inputting more than four spaces would exceed the apparent specification of the code.

Comment: (sidenote) you might want to consume all whitespaces between tokens. what if there are multiple spaces between tokens?

Comment: It's running for me without any seg fault

Answer (score 2):

`command` is uninitialised. That means that the `strlen(command)` call might run beyond the 500 bytes, causing a segmentation fault.

Initialise your `command` array before using it. For example with `memset`.

Other than that, there is no bounds checking whatsoever and some arbitrary array lengths. This is bound to fail.

Comment: Where does it segfault? You can use a debugger to find out.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with `tokens`. You are incrementing `j` and `k` in each iteration without any check.

Anyway, dou you know there already exists functions that do what you wanna do?

Answer (score 0):

To add More into other folks answer, you can use strsep.  Look at the following sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main ()
{
char * command=NULL, *tok=NULL;

command =strdup("asdadas asdasdas asdadas");
while ((tok = strsep(&command, " ")) != NULL )
{
  printf ("..%s..\n", tok);
}
```

Hope it helps. ;)